# how to express this in regex

Tags: regex

I have this :

```
<title>Title</title>
```

All I want to do is express this in regex. I have:

```
/<[A-Za-z]>\w<\/[A-Za-z]>
```

Can anyone help

Comment: What language? Are just trying to match that or do you want to extract the word `Title` (or whatever the title happens to be)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `+` after each of the `[]` and after the `\w` to represent "one or more".

```
/<[A-Za-z]+>\w+<\/[A-Za-z]+>/
```

But it looks like you're trying to parse HTML with regex. [You might want to consider not doing that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a backreference. If you don't then you will match:

```
<title>blabla</otherTag>
```

Try this:

```
/<([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>/
```

Comment: thanks im just beginning to learn regex so thats a little to complex for me right now

Comment: Oh, then I would recommend you to read this tutorial, particularly this chapter: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html